# Console- Visual Studio Code- Where is this? Only see Debug Console

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, console

I am trying to access the console of Visual Studio Code, but I can not. I can not type in the Debug Console. I am trying to use 'typeof' command but keep getting the zsh:command not found error.

[Tutorial snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4b4L.png)

Answer (score 0):

That console is actually the browser console. If you right click or command click on your browser click inspect and then Console.